# How to read this file in R

Tags: r, read.table

I have the following file:

```
GroupA Whatever1 A B C
GroupB Whatever2 C D
GroupC Whatever3 E F G H
```

Columns 1 and 2 should be read as separate columns. The remainder of each line should not be split at tabs and should make the third column. Here is one ugly way of doing this:

```
foo <- read.table( text="GroupA Whatever1 A B C
GroupB Whatever2 C D
GroupC Whatever3 E F G H", fill=T, header=F)
foo2 <- data.frame( foo$V1, foo$V2, 
  V3=apply( foo[,-c(1,2)], 1, 
    function(x) paste0( x, collapse="\t")))
```

The result is what I would like to have:

```
> foo2
  foo.V1    foo.V2         V3
1 GroupA Whatever1  A\tB\tC\t
2 GroupB Whatever2   C\tD\t\t
3 GroupC Whatever3 E\tF\tG\tH
```

Is there a better way? Preferably one that does not require to first split and then paste again the columns? Some of these lines in the table are very, very long.

Comment: Are there delimiters in the source file or just spaces? Also, are there spaces *within* the first two columns?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with **tidyr**...?

```
> library(tidyr)
> unite(foo,foo_all,V3:V6,sep = "\t")
      V1        V2    foo_all
1 GroupA Whatever1  A\tB\tC\t
2 GroupB Whatever2   C\tD\t\t
3 GroupC Whatever3 E\tF\tG\tH
```

Comment: This has the disadvantage that I still need to read the file foo, unnecessarily splitting the line remainders in columns. The file is huge and some of the lines are very long (thousands of tab separated names), so that read.table creates a data frame with thousands of columns -- mostly empty.

Comment: @January Just thinking out loud...perhaps read the groups of columns separately using `fread` in **data.table**.

Comment: @January ...more broadly, it seems both **readr** and **data.table**'s file input functions are aimed at regular tabular data. But they are both very fast. There may not be too much of a penalty in reading in the full file with one of those tools and then collapsing it in memory.

Comment: @joran, `fread` won't read irregular (non-rectangular) data. There is no equivalent to `fill = TRUE` from `read.table`.

Comment: At the moment, I have solved it by reading without a separator (everything in one column) and using gsub to split the strings into three columns.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider a string-splitting function that lets you specify the number of resulting pieces. For instance, you might be able to use `stri_split_fixed` from the "stringi" package.

Here, I assume you've used `readLines` to get the text in from your file:

```
text <- c("GroupA Whatever1 A B C", 
          "GroupB Whatever2 C D", 
          "GroupC Whatever3 E F G H")

library(stringi)

stri_split_fixed(text, " ", 3, simplify = TRUE)
#      [,1]     [,2]        [,3]     
# [1,] "GroupA" "Whatever1" "A B C"  
# [2,] "GroupB" "Whatever2" "C D"    
# [3,] "GroupC" "Whatever3" "E F G H"
```

From there, if you really wanted to replace spaces with tabs in the last column, that should be a very straightforward `gsub` operation.

Answer (score 0):

Why not some command-line manipulation of your dataset using `awk`? (or another language like python, perl, ect)

Here a solution with `awk`. First you need to know the maximum number of columns of your dataset:

```
foo=$(awk "BEGIN{max=0} {if(NF>max) max=NF} END{print max}" dataset_file_name)
```

Now you can use the awk script, passing to it the parameter we have just calculated, and redirecting the output to a new file:

```
awk -f my_script.awk -v max=$foo dataset_file_name > my_new_dataset
```

In R you have to specify the separator (a blank space):

```
bar <- read.table("my_new_dataset", sep=" ")
```

And you'll get the same result of the example you have posted.

---

Here's the code of *my_script.awk*:

```
{
  printf("%s %s ", $1, $2);
  for(i=3; i<NF; i++) printf("%s/t", $i);
  printf("%s", $NF)
  if(NF<max)
    for(i=1; i<(max=1-NF); i++) printf("\t");
  printf("\n");
}
```

---

Another possible solution could be to split the dataset file into two separate files, the first one with the first two columns and the second one with all the others columns. That way maybe you'll find easier to import and manipulate the third column of your dataset.

On the command line:

```
cut -f -2 dataset_file_name > dataset_columns_1_2
cut -f 3- dataset_file_name > dataset_rest_of_columns
```

[Note: the separator for `cut` is **tab**, if the columns separator is different, use the `-d` option (for more info `cut --help`).]

Actually I cannot see any real advantage by using this approach... but I think that the `cut` command could be useful in some other occasions.